# Putting text value on top of the imageBackground

Tags: react-native, textinput, react-props

I try to pass text input value on top of the imageBackground after i press the button addText() which triggers the function.I succeed to pass my value into alert box, but I am not sure how to pass the text input value into other component. I want my text input be shown on top of the imageBackground.

Filter.js file:

```
<View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center' }}>
                <Button title="Capture Device Screenshot" onPress={this.captureScreenFunction} />
                <ImageBackground source={{ uri: this.state.imageURI }} style={{ width: 200, height: 300, marginTop: 5, alignSelf: 'center' }} >
                    <Text>{this.text}</Text>
                </ImageBackground>
                <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row', justifyContent: 'space-around' }}>
                    <View>
                        <NewText />
                    </View>
                </View>
            </View>
```

NewText.js:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, Image, Button, Platform, TouchableOpacity, TextInput, ImageBackground } from 'react-native';

export default class NewText extends Component {

    constructor(props) {

        super(props);

        this.state = {
            text: '',
        }
    }

    addText = () => {
       let newItem = this.state.text;
       alert( newItem )
    }

    render() {

        return (

            <View>
                <TextInput
                    ref="newItemText"
                    style={{ height: 40 }}
                    placeholder="Type something..."
                    onChangeText={(text) => this.setState({ text })}
                    //value = {this.state.text}
                />
                <Button onPress={this.addText} title={'Add text'} />
            </View>
        )


    }
}
```

Comment: Did you try changing the part in my comment?

Answer (score 0):

```
export default class NewText extends Component {

    constructor(props) {

        super(props);

        this.state = {
            text: '',
            putText:false 
        }
    }

    addText = () => {
       let newItem = this.state.text;
       alert( newItem )
    }

    render() {

        return (
            <View>
                 <ImageBackground source={{ uri: this.state.imageURI }} style={{ width: 200, height: 300, marginTop: 5, alignSelf: 'center' }} >
                    <Text>{this.state.putText ? this.state.text : ''}</Text>
                </ImageBackground>
                <TextInput
                    ref="newItemText"
                    style={{ height: 40 }}
                    placeholder="Type something..."
                    onChangeText={(text) => this.setState({ text })}
                    //value = {this.state.text}
                />
                <Button onPress={()=>this.setState({putText:true})} title={'Add text'} />
            </View>
        )

    }
}
```

just check condition whether you clicked add  button or not and take text display decision.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly your question:

Filter.js file:

```
<Text>{this.state.changedText}</Text>
...
<NewText onChange={(changedText) => this.setState({changedText}) />
```

NewText.js:

```
addText = () => {
   let newItem = this.state.text
   this.props.onChange(newItem)
}
```